# Multiple image capture using emgucv library

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I'm trying to build a program that would take a picture of a user 3 times and save those pictures in the desktop my problem is it only saves the picture instead of taking the picture 3 times.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     bool useCam = true;
     if (!useCam)
        measureImage(null);
     else 
     {
        try
        {
             camera = new Capture();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
           return;
        }

        Application.Idle += viewImage;
        captureProcess = true;
     }
}
```

here is the capturing code...

```
private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
    {
        if (captureProcess == true)
        {
            string data="";
            Application.Idle -= viewImage;

            SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               img.ToBitmap().Save(@"C:\\Users\\Julie\\Desktop\\" + ctr + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

                        data = dlg.FileName + ".bmp";
                        MessageBox.Show(data);
                        measureImage(data);
                        Form1_Load(sender, e);
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }

        }

    }
            captureProcess = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming `captureProcess` is a variable at the window scope, you're setting it to false within the first `for` loop, so the 2nd and 3rd never execute due to the `if(captureProcess == true)` check.

Comment: sorry sir I've edited the code the captureProcess=false is outside the forloop